# Reducing dates not working in javascript

Tags: javascript

Trying to work out how I can get 10 days preceding current date in a select box, populated using ng-option. This is the code for reducing dates

```js
var n = 1;
    var d = new Date();
    var dateList = [];
    while (n < 10) {
        d.setDate(d.getDate() - n);
        dateList.push(d);
        n++;
    }
    console.log(dateList);
```

I have swapped n for 1 or any number, but for some reason, I only get the same date gets repeated 10 times.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: you have created one date only and changing that one instance .. you need to create instance of date inside loop

Answer (score 0):

Because you push *the same date* nine times and mutate that in the loop. You want to get 9 different date objects, which you can easily clone as:

```
  dateList.push(new Date(d));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
dayinms = 86400000
da = [];
for (i=1;i<=10;i++) {
    d= new Date()
    d.setTime(d.getTime() - (dayinms * i))
    ds = d.getDate() + '/' + d.getMonth() + '/' + d.getFullYear()
    da[i-1]=ds
}
console.log(da)
```